# Check if dictionary contain another dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries:

```
dict1 = {"Name":"x", "Surname":"y", "Age":30}

dict2 = {"Name":"x", "Surname":"y"}
```

I want a condition like this:

```
if dict2 in dict1:
    return True
```

If I run this code it returns:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

Solutions?

Comment: `in` compares keys, and expects the value you're comparing is a valid type to be a key. You can't have a `dict` as a key as it's unhashable.

Comment: I've notice :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
dict1 = {"Name": "Bob", "Surname": "Smith", "Age": 30}

dict2 = {"Name": "Bob", "Surname": "Smith"}

print(all(dict1[k] == v for k, v in dict2.items()))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following:

```
all(item in dict1.items() for item in dict2.items())
```

you will have to iterate on the dicts elements

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you if you only want to check whether the keys are already present :

```
if all(key in dict1 for key in dict2):
    return True
```

If you want to check whether the values also match as well, try this :

```
if all(kv in dict1.items() for kv in dict2.items()):
    return True
```

Comment: This does not check whether the `values` match also. This is, according to the example posted by OP, what OP actually wants.

Comment: @CaptainTrojan In the question it was not explicit. Anyway updated.

Comment: I changed my -1 to +1, but do you actually believe that? Why would they specify both `names` as `x` and `surnames` as `y`? Do you think that's coincidence? That it is not safe to assume OP wanted precisely this?